# Why won't a comma work to shorten numbers? (# ##0.0,,)

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I am trying to shorten some numbers in cells in Excel so that they display as millions. I tried putting two commas after the number format code in the custom category of the format cells dialog box, but that just returned the numbers with two commas after them, as opposed to the numbers with the decimal place shifted leftwards by 6 places.

[image: Screenshot]

The code I used was: `# ##0.0,,`. My regional settings are set so that decimal points are `.`'s, digit grouping symbols are 's (spaces) and list separators are `;`'s.

Why is this happening and what can I do to shorten the numbers?

Comment: Your regional settings aren't set to understand commas so Excel will not understand commas.

Answer (score 1):

I need to use the code `# ##0.0`

where the code ends off with two *spaces* instead of commas. This is due to my regional settings. A comma is used for the thousands separator on other computers, whereas a space is used for the thousands separator on my computer, so the equivalent code uses the corresponding symbol on my computer.